# Treetop: parsing string literals?

Tags: ruby, treetop

So, I am trying to learn me a bit of ruby, a bit of TDD and a bit of Treetop.

I have the following grammar for parsing string literals:

```
grammar Str
  rule string
    '"'
    (
      !'"' . / '\"'
    )*
    '"'
  end
end
```

And the following test method:

```
def test_strings
  assert @parser.parse('"Hi there!"')
  assert !@parser.parse('"This is not" valid')
  assert @parser.parse('"He said, \"Well done!\""')
end
```

The third test (the one with the backslashes) does not pass (the string is not parsed): why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swap the order of the escaped-quote check:

```
(
  '\"' / !'"' .
)*
```

As another example, your grammar would also match this:

```
"he said, \"
```

Flipping the check correctly fails that as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was it ! Funnily enough, the example I posted was the one that features in the official documentation [here](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/pitfalls_and_advanced_techniques.html)

Comment: Just a note: the example is now fixed int the Treetop website.